# npm run dev 98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin>This dependency was not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, sass

I want to integrate google map in my laravel project and I got the below error when running npm run dev:

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 10:52:34 PM
This dependency was not found:

- /var/www/project_name/resources/sass/app.scss in multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

To install it, you can run: npm install --save /var/www/project_name/resources/sass/app.scss
Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/js/app.js  7.23 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react' from '/var/www/project_name'
at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:90:15)
at resolveStandardizedName (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
at resolvePreset (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:58:10)
at loadPreset (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:77:20)
at createDescriptor (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
at Array.map ()
at createDescriptors (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
at createPresetDescriptors (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
at presets (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
at mergeChainOpts (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:416:26)
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:374:7
at Generator.next ()
at loadFileChain (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:228:24)
at loadFileChain.next ()
at buildRootChain (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:135:29)
at buildRootChain.next ()
at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:101:62)
at loadPrivatePartialConfig.next ()
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:140:25
at Generator.next ()
at step (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:261:32)
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:273:13
at async.call.result.err.err (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:189:28
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:72:7
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:113:33
at step (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:287:14)
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:273:13
at async.call.result.err.err (/var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:223:11)
at /var/www/project_name/node_modules/gensync/index.js:189:28
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
@ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss /js/app[0]

ERROR in multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'css-loader' in '/var/www/project_name'
@ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss /js/app[1]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! project_name@ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project_name@ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-11T22_52_34_252Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! project_name@ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project_name@ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-12-11T22_52_34_309Z-debug.log

I tried different things and none worked:
npm update
npm uninstall --save-dev sass-loader
npm install --save-dev sass-loader@7.1.0
npm install --save
npm install

but the error persist when I run npm run dev.

Comment: did you get any solution for above issue ?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when I tried to use

import {someFunction} from '';

, i.e. I forgot to specify the package to import from.

When I fixed the import I compiled with no issue.